# Animations not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uiviewanimation, uipangesturerecognizer

I present a view controller modally in my application. I'd like for the user to be able to "flick" the view away with a gesture. I wrote the code below for that:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGFloat elasticThreshold = 100;
    CGFloat dismissThreshold = 200;
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat newY = 0;
    CGFloat translationFactor = 0.5;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (translation.y < dismissThreshold) {
            newY = 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (translation.y > elasticThreshold) {
            CGFloat frictionLength = translation.y - elasticThreshold;
            CGFloat frictionTranslation = 30 * atan(frictionLength/120) + frictionLength/10;
            newY = frictionTranslation + (elasticThreshold * translationFactor);
        } else {
            newY = translation.y*translationFactor;
        }
    }

    if (translation.y > dismissThreshold) {
        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                self.overlay.effect = nil;
                self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, self.view.frame.size.height);
            }];
            [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.1 relativeDuration:0.1 animations:^{
                self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-200)/2, self.view.frame.size.height, 200, 20);
            }];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, newY);
        self.pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (newY+self.collectionView.frame.size.height)-20);
    }
}
```

This is hooked up to a `UIGestureRecognizer`:

```
self.pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
self.pan.delegate = self;
self.pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.pan];
```

However, what happens is that the completion block executes immediately. So you'll see the view move down (because of `dismissViewControllerAnimated`) and at the same time see the `overlay.effect` go away. However, what I would like is for my animations to happen and then for the view controller to dismiss itself silently.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Comment: what is happening with the rest of the gesture handling? Are you moving the view when the gesture state is changed? It seems odd to only do anything when the pan has ended

Comment: I'm moving it back to 0 when the pan ends. Otherwise I'm moving the view down, yeah.

Comment: but that code isn't in your question

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread, the if statement only applies to the first part of the code. It's generally cleaner to use a switch for the gesture state in your handling code :)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you are **nesting** `UIView` animation blocks. You should use `dispatch_after` for this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: I'm not nesting? I just add keyframes to `animateKeyframesWithDuration`. But delaying the dismissal of the view controller could work, yeah.

Comment: @user4992124 The point is that you are invocating blocks inside the main block and that triggers the completion block to run sooner than expected.

Comment: This still causes the view to be dismissed almost instantly.

Comment: This is neither the problem, nor a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A UIView keyframe (or standard) animation will execute its completion block immediately if there is no work to be done. It won't wait for the duration of the animation if there is nothing to animate.

It seems that in your case when you are kicking off the dismiss animation, the views are already in their final state, hence there is no animation and the completion block is run immediately.